# Troubleshooting LlamaIndex SQL Query: Incorrect 'No Record Found' Response for Existing Data

Tags: sql, llama, llama-index

I'm working on a Python project using LlamaIndex with SQLAlchemy to query a MySQL database. The project involves executing natural language SQL queries using the NLSQLTableQueryEngine from LlamaIndex. However, I'm encountering an unexpected issue where the query engine consistently returns a response indicating that a record does not exist, even though the data is present in the database.

```
import logging
import sys
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
from llama_index import (
    SimpleDirectoryReader,
    VectorStoreIndex,
    ServiceContext,
)
from llama_index import SQLDatabase
from llama_index.llms import LlamaCPP
from llama_index.llms.llama_utils import (
    messages_to_prompt,
    completion_to_prompt,
)
from llama_index.indices.struct_store.sql_query import NLSQLTableQueryEngine
from llama_index.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbedding

model_url = "https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/Llama-2-13B-chat-GGUF/resolve/main/llama-2-13b-chat.Q4_0.gguf"

llm = LlamaCPP(
    model_url=model_url,
    model_path=None,
    temperature=0.1,
    max_new_tokens=256,
    context_window=3900,
    generate_kwargs={},
    model_kwargs={"n_gpu_layers": 1},
    messages_to_prompt=messages_to_prompt,
    completion_to_prompt=completion_to_prompt,
    verbose=True,
)
embed_model = "local:BAAI/bge-large-en"
def setup_logging():
    logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO, force=True)
    logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout))
    
def create_db_engine():
    db_user = "user"
    db_password = "pass"
    db_host = "localhost"
    db_port = "3309"
    db_name = "classicmodels"
    connection_string = f"mysql+pymysql://{db_user}:{db_password}@{db_host}:{db_port}/{db_name}"
    return create_engine(connection_string)    

def test_db_connection(engine):
    with engine.connect() as connection:
        result = connection.execute(text("select * from customers limit 3"))
        for row in result:
            print(row)
            

def create_sql_database(engine):
    return SQLDatabase(engine, sample_rows_in_table_info=2)

def create_query_engine(sql_database, service_context):
    return NLSQLTableQueryEngine(
        sql_database=sql_database,
        tables = ["customers", "orders"],
        service_context=service_context
    )

def main():
    setup_logging()
    engine = create_db_engine()
    test_db_connection(engine)
    sql_database = create_sql_database(engine)
    service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(    llm=llm,    embed_model=embed_model,    )
    query_engine = create_query_engine(sql_database, service_context)
    response = query_engine.query("when was order number 10100 shipped?")
    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The specific query I'm testing is "when was order number 10100 shipped?".

A query is that:
'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders;\n\nThis query will return the count of all rows in the "orders" table.\n\nPlease provide the results of the query so I can assist you further.'

Despite the order number 10100 existing in the orders table, the response I receive is:
"I apologize for the confusion. Based on the information provided, it appears that there is no record of order number 10100 in the orders table. Therefore, there is no shipped date to retrieve. Is there anything else I can assist you with?"

This is perplexing because the order number 10100 definitely exists in the orders table. I've tested the database connection and it's working fine, as I can retrieve data using other SQL queries.

I'm looking for insights into why the NLSQLTableQueryEngine might be returning this incorrect response.

Here are some points I've considered:

Could this be an issue with how LlamaIndex interprets the natural language query?
Is there a possibility that the table setup or query engine configuration in LlamaIndex is missing something crucial?
Any suggestions or insights into what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not familiar with that tool, but from the docs it looks like it retains enough metadata to test the generated query directly. Try printing and running what you get back from response.metadata["sql_query"]

Comment: One of the querys is: 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders;\n\nThis query will return the count of all rows in the "orders" table.\n\nPlease provide the results of the query so I can assist you further.' is what IT returns. The query works.

Comment: @Gatso90 have you found a solution to this problem? I'm facing the same issue.